# Why does Spring AOP use CGLIB despite the fact that the target class implements the interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, java-11

> Spring AOP is a proxy-based AOP framework. This means that to implement aspects to the target objects, it'll create proxies of that object. This is achieved using either of two ways:
>
> - JDK dynamic proxy – the preferred way for Spring AOP. Whenever the targeted object implements even one interface, then JDK dynamic proxy will be used
> - CGLIB proxy – if the target object doesn't implement an interface, then CGLIB proxy can be used

[source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-vs-aspectj#3-internal-structure-and-application)

And yet, CGLIB is always used... This applies both to the standard Spring delivery (for example, using the @Transactional annotation) and using its written aspect

```java
public interface MyService {

    void methodFirst();

    void methodSecond();
}
```

```java
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    @AnnotationCustom
    public void methodFirst() {
        System.out.println("methodFirst()");
        methodSecond();
    }

    @Override
    @AnnotationCustom
    public void methodSecond() {
        System.out.println("methodSecond()");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class AopTransactionalSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AopTransactionalSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectCustom {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {}

    @Pointcut("@annotation(aop.transactional.spring.aop.annotation.AnnotationCustom)")
    public void annotatedMethodCustom() {}

    @Before("annotatedMethodCustom() && publicMethod()")
    public void printSomeMessage() {
        System.out.println(" AspectCustom");
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class AopTransactionalSpringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AopTransactionalSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
```

- test

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AopTransactionalSpringApplicationTests {
}
```

```java
class MyServiceTest extends AopTransactionalSpringApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void methodFirst() {

        myService.methodFirst();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

- pom.xml

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source-target.version>11</java.source-target.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The documentation says that if we use the interface, then JDK will be used, and if the target class does not implement the interface, then inheritance will be used and then CGLIB will create a proxy, inheriting from the target class . But in debug mode, I actually observe something else .

Why is that?

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, please point out the mistakes in my understanding of this issue.

Comment: Because Spring Boot by default enables class proxies. As you are looking at the Spring Framework documentation not the Spring Boot documentation.

Comment: I want to add that AFAIK, in Boot due to inconsistent combinations of settings, presently there is no way to reinstate the default Spring behaviour, which is unfortunate. Corresponding config settings are being ignored.

Comment: And I thought about how to change the default behavior and remove the use of CGLIB since I program on interfaces

Comment: By setting the property `spring.aop.proxy-target-class` to `false` in your `application.properties`. Also the settings aren't ignored **but** if one part of the AOP requires or is turned to class based proxies **everything** switches to class based proxies. Finally do you really want to use the non-default? Why do you try so hard to use the JDK proxies as opposed to the class proxies, they both work? What is your gain in this?

Comment: For each tested instance of CGLIB, two objects are created: the actual proxied object and an instance of the subclass that implements the advice. In addition, I would like to check how the method call from the same class will work and how the end-to-end logic will be bound to it

Comment: spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false :  I used this property and saw the use of JDK-proxy. But even this did not help to implement the aspect in a method that is called from the same class (I checked the assumption that such a move saves the situation from using Spring AOP). I made sure that this is a feature of Spring AOP and if we want to embed an aspect in a method that is called from this class. we should use 'compile weaving', and for this we should use AspectJ

Comment: JDK proxies also instanciate at least 2 objects: 1 instance of the target class and 1 proxy for each of its interfaces. Method calls from the same class will never be proxied since the instance does not see its own proxy – except, as you said, with bytecode weaving (which does not require proxies anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Further to @m-deinum response, according to official Spring boot documentation:

*By default, Spring Boot’s auto-configuration configures Spring AOP to use CGLib proxies. To use JDK proxies instead, set configprop:spring.aop.proxy-target-class to false.*

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.aop